# login with active directory autentication in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, c#-3.0, active-directory-group

I am creating the `asp.net web application`. In that I used **active directory for login**. I have one group named **Validusers**, when user logged in it checks the user to that **validusers** group. If the user exists in the group then login is successful, if not login failed.

I did all the things, it works good in my local machine, but it is not working when I publishing the website. I got the following error

```
 Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

On my machine it works good,while publishing i got an error.i used below code for your reference

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainName");
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity MyIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string LogUser = MyIdentity.Name.ToString();
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, LogUser);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "Validusers");Validusers---->Groupname
 if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
 {
    Login success
 }
else
{
Login Failed
}
```

it will check logged user with Validusers group.if the user exists in the group then login is success other wise failed login. I got an error when i published this website.please give some solution

Comment: Where are you publishing? do you have **Integrated Windows Authentication** ticked in IIS?

Comment: i need to host the website to the server.for that i am publishing website

Comment: This is an Intranet application, and you are publishing on a server within the domain?

Comment: yes.i am publishing application with in the domain.can you give clear clarity about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Although you had supplied so little information about the domain and network relationship with your development machine and web server, I assume the web server has no physical connection to the Active Directory server that you depend your code on. Then it should be impossible for web server to query the AD directory.
If web and AD servers are on same network than you may need to work on the firewall settings of both web server and AD server to make sure that they can communicate. 
If web and AD server have no communication problems you should check the availability of that "Validusers" to a code running at web server.
As IIS applications run with the user account that is defined for the application pool that hosts the application, you should make sure that the app pool identity has enough rights to access those delicate information.